# Get property from local variable by string

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke

Inside a method i make a few web service calls to get data, like so:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var user = userWS.GetUsers();
    var documents = documentWS.GetDocuments();
}
```

I also have an XML file in which a user can tell what property to map. The XML sort of looks like this:

```
<root>
  <item id="username" mapper="user.username.value" />
  <item id="document1" mapper="documents.document1.value" />
</root>
```

So what i basically want to do is execute to string that is inside the `mapper` attribute. So that i have something like this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var user = userWS.GetUsers();
    var documents = documentWS.GetDocuments();

    // returns: "user.username.value"
    string usernameProperty = GetMapperValueById ( "username" );

    var value = Invoke(usernameProperty);
}
```

So it should act as if i was calling `var value = user.username.value;` manually in my code.

But how can i invoke this action from a `string`?

Comment: I've provided `GetPropertyValue` method that will suit your needs in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936888/c-sharp-developing-net3-5-using-reflection-to-get-set-values-to-nested-properti/19938840#19938840)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the answer i'm looking for. This is about a local variable from inside a method that i need to execute. I think i need more of an `Eval` function for this. But unfortunately that isn't as easy as i thought it would be

Comment: it will be enough, I'm going to provide an answer with proper example.

Comment: @Vivendi the only way to execute dynamic code would be via [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). However, you could do this using reflection - it just won't be as simple as you would like it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't get values of local variables at runtime (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929384/c-sharp-reusable-function-to-dump-current-value-of-local-variables) for reference), but based on my own [answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936888/c-sharp-developing-net3-5-using-reflection-to-get-set-values-to-nested-properti/19938840#19938840), you can use method `GetPropertyValue` to workaround this problem creating a local object with desired properties:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var container = new 
    {
        user = userWS.GetUsers(),
        documents = documentWS.GetDocuments()
    }

    // returns: "user.username.value"
    string usernameProperty = GetMapperValueById ( "username" );

    var value = GetPropertyValue(container, usernameProperty);
}

static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyPath)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo result = null;
    string[] pathSteps = propertyPath.Split('.');
    object currentObj = obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < pathSteps.Length; ++i)
    {
        Type currentType = currentObj.GetType();
        string currentPathStep = pathSteps[i];
        var currentPathStepMatches = Regex.Match(currentPathStep, @"(\w+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?");
        result = currentType.GetProperty(currentPathStepMatches.Groups[1].Value);
        if (result.PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            int index = int.Parse(currentPathStepMatches.Groups[2].Value);
            currentObj = (result.GetValue(currentObj) as Array).GetValue(index);
        }
        else
        {
            currentObj = result.GetValue(currentObj);
        }

    }
    return currentObj;
}
```

Comment: +1 the idea of the `container` is a nice touch. This could be further improved by making `GetPropertyValue` generic.

Comment: Thanks alot, this seems to be doing the trick! I changed both  `result.GetValue(currentObj)` to `result.GetValue(currentObj, null)`  in my code, since it expects two params.